# Take picture and save to gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, image-gallery, android-camera-intent

I've spend hours looking into this issue, and I've found no solution (on StackOverflow or otherwise).
My app is targeting API 30 and the minSskVersion is 29. I'm following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

I have a button on my activity that opens the camera using an intent:

```
fun takePhoto() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
              startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
        }
    }
}
```

But I also want to save the picture on the device gallery. So I changed my `takePhoto()` method to:

```
fun takePhoto() {
    Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
            val photoFile: File? = try {
                createImageFile()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
                null
            }

            photoFile?.also {
                try {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        this,
                        "net.filiperamos.photogrid.provider",
                        it
                    )

                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                } catch (ex: IllegalArgumentException) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Could not get file URI.")
                    ex.printStackTrace()
                }

                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and added the `createImageFile()` method:

```
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(Date())
    val filename = "image_$timeStamp"
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

    return File.createTempFile(filename, ".jpg", storageDir).apply {
        currentPhotoPath = absolutePath // Save path for later use
    }
}
```

My Manifest has the camera use and the external writing permission:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I added a provider indie the application tag:

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

and I created the `file_paths.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/net.ramos.photos/files/Pictures/" />
</paths>
```

When I run this code on my device, I get an exception when running `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/net.ramos.photos/files/Pictures/image_20200823_1415398042919497737944663.jpg
```

And if I change my `file_paths.xml` file, replacing `external-files-path`for `external-path`, the error goes away, but no image is stored nowhere.

What am I missing?

Comment: "and I created the file_paths.xml:" -- replace your `path` value with just `Pictures/`. "no image is stored nowhere" -- how are you looking for it? It will not show up in the `MediaStore`, as images stored in that location are no longer indexable. Gallery-style apps are unlikely to pick up the image as a result.

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone now. But I want that pictures taken with my app to be available to other apps. How can I make it accessible from the system's Media Provider?

Comment: For the next year or so, use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and write to a public location, such as the top-level `Pictures/` directory, rather than an app-specific location as you are using right now. At this point, given the whole scoped storage mess and [limits on `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/16/action-image-capture-android-r.html), I have no idea what the plan will be for your desired feature a year from now.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in your manifest file as an attribute of 'application' tag,

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

this should solve the problem you are facing and the exception should go away.

Comment: That did not work: if I keep ```external-files-path``` I still see the error, and if I change it to ```external-path``` I see no error, but I also don't see the image saved. Although it seems, according to @CommonsWare, I'm looking for the photo on the wrong location…